# How can I write all of stdin to stdout without using lots of memory?

Tags: rust

I want to write a Rust program that takes everything in stdin and copies it to stdout. So far I have this

```
fn main() {
    let mut stdin: io::Stdin = io::stdin();    
    let mut stdout: io::Stdout = io::stdout();

    let mut buffer: [u8; 1_000_000] = [0; 1_000_000];
    let mut n_bytes_read: usize = 0;
    let mut uninitialized: bool = true;
    while uninitialized || n_bytes_read > 0
    {
        n_bytes_read = stdin.read(&mut buffer).expect("Could not read from STDIN.");
        uninitialized = false;
    }
}
```

I'm copying everything into a buffer of size one million so as not to blow up the memory if someone feeds my program a 3 gigabyte file. So now I want to copy this to stdout, but the only primitive write operation I can find is `stdout.write(&mut buffer)` - but this writes the whole buffer! I would need a way to write a specific number of bytes, like `stdout.write_only(&mut buffer, n_bytes_read)`.

I'd like to do this in the most basic way possible, with a minimum of standard library imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you wanted to do was copy from stdin to stdout without using much memory, just use [std::io::copy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/fn.copy.html). It streams the data from a reader to a writer.

If your goal is to write part of a buffer, then take a slice of that buffer and pass that to `write`:

```
stdout.write(&buffer[0..n_bytes_read]);
```

A slice does not copy the data so you will not use any more memory.

Note however that `write` may not write everything you have asked - it returns the number of bytes actually written. If you use `write_all` it will write the whole slice.

Comment: Nitpick: the `0` to the left of the range is optional: you can also write `&buffer[..n_bytes_read]`.

Comment: Wow, that's like magic. Even though the slice itself has a size that can't be known at compile time, the pointer can be so it's legal, and it still carries the (dynamic) length of the buffer with it so that `write()` knows what to do with it.